# jquery replace not replacing all spaces with -

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Why is my jquery not replacing all spaces with a `'-'`. It only replaces the first space with a `'-'`

```
$('.modhForm').submit(function(event) {

        var $this = $(this),
            action = $this.attr('action'),
            query = $this.find('.topsearchbar').val(); // Use val() instead of attr('value').

        if (action.length >= 2 && query.length >= 2 && query.lenght <=24) {

          // Use URI encoding
          var newAction = (action + '/' + query.replace(' ','-'));
          console.log('OK', newAction); // DEBUG

          // Change action attribute
          $this.attr('action', newAction);

        } else {
          console.log('To small to be any good'); // DEBUG

          // Do not submit the form
          event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) -- see the second example on this page.

Comment: This is a big problem and raplaceAll not working in all cases. JS and JQuery are a sh*t.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try with this:

```
.replace(/\s/g,"-");
```

### Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYnxm/3/)

Comment: @Norman Which browser are you using? The jsFiddle demo works for me in Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: This works fine in `jsfiddle` so it isn't wrong..there may be some browser compatibility issue..@Norman

Comment: I've updated your fiddle. Can u take a look? I'm using firefox 14.0.1

Comment: Where to take a look.? I didn't find any edit on my answer..@Norman

Comment: Ok..There may be the browser issue..I updated my answer..@Norman

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var str = 'a b c';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('-');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's: "if (action.length >= 2 && query.length >= 2 && **query.length** <=24) {"

Not: "if (action.length >= 2 && query.length >= 2 && **query.lenght** <=24) {"

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace all occurences :

```
query.replace(/\ /g, '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'-');
```

This still works, in case your query is `undefinied` or `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.replace` only replaces the first when its first argument is a string.  To replace all occurrences you need to pass in a global regular expression as the first argument.

> ## [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace)
>
> ...
>
> To perform a global search and replace, either include the g switch in the regular expression or if the first parameter is a string, include g in the flags parameter.

Others have shown a number of regular expressions that work for varying definitions of "space."

Answer (score 0):

You can try with custom function

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (searchText, replacementText) {
    return this.split(searchText).join(replacementText);
};
var text = "This is Sample Text";
text.replaceAll(" ", "-");
//final output(This-is-Sample-Text)
```

Comment: Are you kidding? Javascript and Jquery have not a basic string function. I don't understand why is considered a great programming language

Answer (score -1):

Replace all whitespace (including tabs, spaces, ...):

```
query.replace(/\s/g, '_');
```